# Separate Red And Blue When Blurred

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, node-editor, compositing-nodes, depth-of-field

I want my depth of field to be separated[image: Red and Blue Seperation] like this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add Lens Flares/Halos?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1864/how-can-i-add-lens-flares-halos)

Comment: ..in particular Lens Distortion > Dispersion, to simulate chromatic aberration ..

Comment: Related: [Chromatic aberration, Alpha mask?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94248/chromatic-aberration-alpha-mask/94253#94253)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of a lens distortion node and a mask.

In the lens distortion, chromatic aberration would be controlled by the Dispersion value.

With a mask you can designate areas of the screen that would be affected by such dispersion.

[image]