# Is chromatic aberration possible in blender

Tags: video-sequence-editor, compositing-nodes

Can I separate individual colors of an image/video and add another color around it in other position to achieve chromatic aberration

Comment: is there something specific? internet is quite full of this topic https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/distort/lens_distortion.html or manually https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=199&v=oowaQsxaeD4&feature=emb_title

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can fake Chromatic aberration in the Compositor.
Just add the *Lens Distortion* node and adjust the *Dispersion* value.

[image]

Comment: Here is nice extension https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/94253/2214

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be closer to physically correct, you can make three renders through a lens system with refraction shaders set to slight offsets, take a separate channel from each image, and combine them.

It's quite tedious, though.